# Merging two lists in a certain format in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two lists `A` and `B`. I am trying to merge the two lists into one in a specific format as shown in the expected output. I also show the current output.

```
A=[0, 1]
B=[[1,2],[3,4]]
C=A+B
print(C)
```

The current output is

```
[0, 1, [1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

The expected output is

```
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lst=[]
for x, y in zip(A, B):
    lst.append([x] + y)
#[[0, 1, 2], [1, 3, 4]]
```

Or as @Mechanic Pig suggested in comments using list comprehension:

```
[[a] + b for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `np.insert`:

```
a = np.array([0, 1])
b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
np.insert(b, 0, a, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A=[0, 1]
B=[[1,2],[3,4]]
c=[]
for i in range(len(A)):
    c.append([A[i]])
    for j in range(len(B[i])):
        c[i].append(B[i][j])

print(c)
[[0, 1, 2], [1, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.